# Multiplying 2 32-bit numbers and taking the top 32 bits using AVX2

Tags: c, assembly, x86, low-level, avx2

I am using multiplication (with the addition of other operations) as a substitution for integer division. My solution eventually requires me to multiply 2 32-bit numbers together and take the top 32 bits (just like the mulhi function), but AVX2 does not offer a 32-bit variant of _mm256_mulhi_epu16 (Ex: there's no '_mm256_mulhi_epu32' function).

I have tried various methods such as checking the functions of AVX512, or even manipulating the 32-bit integers to be 2 hi/lo 16-bit integers. I'm very new to working with low-level programming, so I'm unaware what is optimal, or even just possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by doing the following:

```
__m256i t1 = _mm256_mul_epu32(m, n);
t1 = _mm256_srli_epi64(t1, 32);
```

Comment: Yes, you need a shift or shuffle, and a shift is a good choice.  `vpmuludq` 32x32=>64 is faster than an AVX512 64x64=>64 `vpmullq` on current hardware (single uop).  If you had AVX512IFMA you could use [`VPMADD52HUQ`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmadd52huq) but that's the upper 52 of 104 bits.  (It exists to expose the full power of the FP mantissa multipliers for whatever you want to use them for.)